# PL/SQL/Java - SQL Selects, for Loops, if statements and Lists

Tags: java, sql

Right then, I've created an application to create a new booking for a student on a route.
This should them calculate the collision times using a database containing these times.

e.g. Student books an exam for 12:00, program will check for any other tests around that time, it will then check collision times, and if there is a collision it will add 5 minutes to the start time and try again. That's what I'm aiming for.

I know this is far from perfect or correct, but that's why I'm here.

BOOKING CLASS

```
public class Booking
{
    private int bookingId;
    private String route;
    private int startTime;
    private String bookingDate;

    public Booking()
    {
        bookingId = 0000;
        route = "No Route Entered";
        startTime = 0000;
        bookingDate = "No Date entered";
    }

    public int getBookingId()
    {
        return bookingId;
    }

    public String getRoute()
    {
        return route;
    }

    public int getStartTime()
    {
        return startTime;
    }

    public String getBookingDate()
    {
        return bookingDate;
    }

    public void setBookingId(int bookingId)
    {
        this.bookingId = bookingId;
    }

    public void setRoute(String route)
    {
        this.route = route;
    }

    public void setStartTime(int startTime)
    {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public void setBookingDate(String bookingDate)
    {
        this.bookingDate = bookingDate;
    }

    public Booking(int bookingId, String route, int startTime, String bookingDate)
    {
        setBookingId(bookingId);
        setRoute(route);
        setStartTime(startTime);
        setBookingDate(bookingDate);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "BookingId: " + getBookingId() + "\nRoute: " + getRoute() + "\nStart Time: " + getStartTime() +
                "\nBooking Date: " + getBookingDate();
    }
}
```

MAIN CLASS

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Creates new Student and booking">

        Student s1 = new Student();
        Booking b1 = new Booking();
        s1.setStudentId(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ID for Student: [0001]")));
        s1.setFname(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first name of Student: "));
        s1.setLname(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter last name of Student: "));
        s1.setAddress(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter address for Student: "));
        s1.setPhoneNo(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter phone number for Student: "));
        s1.setOtherDetails(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter other details for Student: [Glasses?]"));

        b1.setBookingId(0002);
        b1.setStartTime(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Start time for Booking: [1200]")));
        b1.setBookingDate(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Date for Booking: [01-JAN-12]"));

       int records = 0;

       List <Booking> allBookings = new ArrayList<Booking>();

       allBookings.add(b1);

       for(Booking b:allBookings) {

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, b1.getStartTime());//Get Start Time from user

           //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="To select max time of all routes">
           try {
               Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
               //load the oracle driver...needs to be in classes folder in jre folder
           } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
               System.out.println(
                       " Can't find class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
               System.exit(1);
           }

           Connection conn = null;
           //new connection object
           Statement stmtMax = null;
           //new statemnt object
           ResultSet maxTime = null;
           //new record set object
           try {
               conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.tralee.ie:1521:orcl",
                       "*", "*");
               stmtMax = conn.createStatement();
               // create the statement for this connection
               //</editor-fold>

               maxTime = stmtMax.executeQuery(
               "SELECT MAX(LENGTH) FROM ROUTE");
               // get the results of select query and store in recordset object
               while (maxTime.next()) {
                   // move to first/next record of recordset
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check: Max time of all routes: " + maxTime.getString(1));
                   // output next record using string format
               }
               //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Error handling for Select Statement">
               maxTime.close();
               maxTime = null;
               stmtMax.close();
               stmtMax = null;
               conn.close();
               conn = null;

           } catch (SQLException e) {
               System.out.println(" A SQL error: " + e.getMessage());
           } finally {
               if (maxTime != null) {
                   try {
                       maxTime.close();
                   } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                   }
               }

               if (stmtMax != null) {
                   try {
                       stmtMax.close();
                   } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                   }
               }

               if (conn != null) {
                   try {
                       conn.close();
                   } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                   }
               }
           }
          // </editor-fold>
          //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="To select all bookings within a time">
           try {                   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
               //load the oracle driver...needs to be in classes folder in jre folder
           } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
               System.out.println(
                       " Can't find class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
               System.exit(1);
           }
```

ERROR -

```
Connection conn2 = null;
               //new connection object
               Statement stmtTime = null;
               //new statemnt object
               ResultSet withinTime = null;
               //new record set object
               try {
                   conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.tralee.ie:1521:orcl",
                           "*", "*");
                   stmtTime = conn2.createStatement();
                   // create the statement for this connection
                   //</editor-fold>

                   withinTime = stmtTime.executeQuery(
                   "SELECT * FROM BOOKINGS WHERE" + b1.getStartTime() + "<=" + b1.getStartTime() + "-" + maxTime +
                           "AND" + b1.getStartTime() + ">=" + b1.getStartTime() + "+" + maxTime);
                   // get the results of select query and store in recordset object

                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Check: Bookings within a time: \n" + withinTime.getString(1));

                     while (withinTime.next()) {
                       // move to first/next record of recordset
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Check: Bookings within a time: \n" + withinTime.getString(1));
                       // output next record using string format
                   }
                   //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Error handling for Select Statement">
                   withinTime.close();
                   withinTime = null;
                   stmtTime.close();
                   stmtTime = null;
                   conn2.close();
                   conn2 = null;
               } catch (SQLException e) {
                   System.out.println(" A SQL error: " + e.getMessage());
               } finally {
                   if (withinTime != null) {
                       try {
                           withinTime.close();
                       } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                       }
                   }

                   if (stmtTime != null) {
                       try {
                           stmtTime.close();
                       } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                       }
                   }

                   if (conn2 != null) {
                       try {
                           conn2.close();
                       } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                       }
                   }
               }
    //END OF ERROR

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="To select all free routes">
try {                       Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                   //load the oracle driver...needs to be in classes folder in jre folder
               } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                   System.out.println(
                           " Can't find class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                   System.exit(1);
               }

               Connection conn3 = null;
               //new connection object
               Statement stmtFreeR = null;
               //new statemnt object
               ResultSet freeRoute = null;
               //new record set object
               try {
                   conn3 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.tralee.ie:1521:orcl",
                           "*", "*");
                   stmtFreeR = conn3.createStatement();
                   // create the statement for this connection

                   freeRoute = stmtFreeR.executeQuery(
                   " SELECT ROUTEID FROM Route MINUS SELECT ROUTEID FROM Booking ");
                   // get the results of select query and store in recordset object

                   while (freeRoute.next()) {
                       // move to first/next record of recordset
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check: Select all free RouteId's: " + freeRoute.getString(1));
                       //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " the answer is " + fRoutes);
                       // output next record using string format
                   }

             //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="To randomize free routes">

   //ERROR -- Does not do anything?

               if( freeRoute != null) {

                List RouteX = new ArrayList();

                while (freeRoute.next()) {
                    RouteX.add(freeRoute.getString(1));

                    Collections.shuffle(RouteX);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Free routes list: " + RouteX);

                }
               }
            else {
                List RouteX = new ArrayList();

                while (freeRoute.next()) {
                    RouteX.add(freeRoute.getString(1));

                    Collections.shuffle(RouteX);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Free routes list: " + RouteX);
                }
            }

                   //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Error handling for Select Statement">
                   freeRoute.close();
                   freeRoute = null;
                   stmtFreeR.close();
                   stmtFreeR = null;
                   conn3.close();
                   conn3 = null;

               } catch (SQLException e) {
                   System.out.println(" A SQL error: " + e.getMessage());

               } finally {
                   if (freeRoute != null) {
                       try {
                           freeRoute.close();
                       } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                       }
                   }

                   if (stmtFreeR != null) {
                       try {
                           stmtFreeR.close();
                       } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                       }
                   }

                   if (conn3 != null) {
                       try {
                           conn3.close();
                       } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                       }
                   }
               }

                //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="To count number of routes">
               try {
                   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                   //load the oracle driver...needs to be in classes folder in jre folder
               } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                   System.out.println(
                           " Can't find class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                   System.exit(1);
               }

               Connection conn4 = null;
               //new connection object
               Statement stmtCountR = null;
               //new statemnt object
              // ResultSet countRoutes = null;
               //new record set object
               try {
                   conn4 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.tralee.ie:1521:orcl",
                           "*", "*");
                   stmtCountR = conn4.createStatement();
                   // create the statement for this connection
                   //</editor-fold>

                String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ROUTE";
                PreparedStatement prest = conn4.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = prest.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()){
                records = rs.getInt(1);

              }
              //System.out.println("Number of records: " + records);
                       // move to first/next record of recordset
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Number of total routes: " + records);
                       //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " the answer is " + fRoutes);
                       // output next record using string format

                   //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Error handling for Select Statement">
                  // countRoutes.close();
                   //countRoutes = null;
                   rs.close();
                   rs = null;
                   stmtCountR.close();
                   stmtCountR = null;
                   conn4.close();
                   conn4 = null;

               } catch (SQLException e) {
                   System.out.println(" A SQL error: " + e.getMessage());

               }/* finally {
                   if (countRoutes != null) {
                       try {
                           countRoutes.close();
                       } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                       }
                   }*/

                   if (stmtCountR != null) {
                       try {
                           stmtCountR.close();
                       } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                       }
                   }

                   if (conn4 != null) {
                       try {
                           conn4.close();
                       } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                       }
                   }
               }

    //ERROR - for(r[X]) -- Looking to assign R with an incremented X value. i.e. R1, R2, R3 --

               for(int X = 1; X < records; X++) {

                    for(r[X]) {

                //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="To check if RX is in Collision Table">
               try {
                   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                   //load the oracle driver...needs to be in classes folder in jre folder
               } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                   System.out.println(
                           " Can't find class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                   System.exit(1);
               }

               Connection conn5 = null;
               //new connection object
               Statement stmtFindRx = null;
               //new statemnt object
               ResultSet checkRx = null;
               //new record set object
               try {
                   conn5 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.tralee.ie:1521:orcl",
                           "*", "*");
                   stmtFindRx = conn5.createStatement();
                   // create the statement for this connection
                       checkRx = stmtFindRx.executeQuery(
                       "*********");
                       // get the results of select query and store in recordset object

                       while (checkRx.next()) {
                       // move to first/next record of recordset
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " the answer is " + checkRx.getString(1));

                       // output next record using string format
                   }
                   //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Error handling for Select Statement">
                   checkRx.close();
                   checkRx = null;
                   stmtFindRx.close();
                   stmtFindRx = null;
                   conn5.close();
                   conn5 = null;

               } catch (SQLException e) {
                   System.out.println(" A SQL error: " + e.getMessage());
               } finally {
                   if (checkRx != null) {
                       try {
                           checkRx.close();
                       } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                       }
                   }
                   if (stmtFindRx != null) {
                       try {
                           stmtFindRx.close();
                       } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                       }
                   }

                   if (conn5 != null) {
                       try {
                           conn5.close();
                       } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                       }
                   }
               }
                    }

               }
```

ERROR - Then check if RX is = the route entered, if he same add 5mins on.

```
           if(R[X].equals(b1.getRoute())) {

              b1.setStartTime(b1.getStartTime() + 0005);
           } else {

           String strConn = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.tralee.ie:1521:orcl";
           String strUser = "*";
           String strPassword = "*";

           try {
            Driver drv = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
            DriverManager.registerDriver(drv);
            Connection conn6 = DriverManager.getConnection(strConn, strUser, strPassword);
            //code to execute commands...

            //Booking Insert
            String query1 = "INSERT INTO Booking(BOOKINGID, BOOKINGTYPE, LNAME, STARTTIME, " +
            "BOOKINGDATE, HISTORY) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            PreparedStatement pstmt1 = conn6.prepareStatement(query1);
            pstmt1.setInt(1, b1.getBookingId());
            pstmt1.setDouble(3, b1.getStartTime());
            pstmt1.setString(4, b1.getBookingDate());
            pstmt1.executeUpdate();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Booking Confirmed");

            conn6.close();
            }

            catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(" A SQL error: " + e.getMessage());
               }
            }
          }
       }
```

The Last error I'm not too bothered about yet, and I know it's not good to create a new connection everytime and in a loop, I will sort this later. But for now, what I am asking is

1) Why won't this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKINGS WHERE" +
 b1.getStartTime() + "<=" + b1.getStartTime() + "-" + maxTime +
 "AND" + b1.getStartTime() + ">=" + b1.getStartTime() + "+" + maxTime);
```

return the bookings within the start time plus the max time of all routes? and how do I fix this?

2) How do I adjust this, so that when the select is called, and returns the values of all the Free unbooked routes, it will insert it into an List and shuffle the list and return the route value?

The select runs and returns the correct values, although this error appears:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>                    " SELECT ROUTEID FROM Route MINUS SELECT ROUTEID FROM Booking ");

```
               while (freeRoute.next()) {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check: Select all free RouteId's: " + freeRoute.getString(1));

               }

           if( freeRoute != null) {
            List RouteX = new ArrayList();

            while (freeRoute.next()) {
                RouteX.add(freeRoute.getString(1));

                Collections.shuffle(RouteX);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Free routes list: " + RouteX);
            }
           }
        else {
            List RouteX = new ArrayList();

            while (freeRoute.next()) {
                RouteX.add(freeRoute.getString(1));

                Collections.shuffle(RouteX);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Free routes list: " + RouteX);
            }
        }
```

And 3) This for statement, I want it to assign R with the X value, and basically say 
        for each R[X Value] then the body of the for statement?

```
for(int X = 1; X < records; X++) {

                for(r[X]) {
```

I know I'm asking a lot here, but if someone could shed some light on what I need to change to get these things firing, it be very grateful.

EDIT:

BOOKINGS TABLE

```
    CREATE BOOKING
      (
        BOOKINGID NUMBER(4,0),
        STARTTIME NUMBER(4,0),
        BOOKINGDATE DATE,
        EXAMINERID NUMBER(4,0),
        STUDENTID  NUMBER(4,0),
        ROUTEID    NUMBER(4,0),
        CONSTRAINT BOOKING_PK PRIMARY KEY (BOOKINGID)
CONSTRAINT EXAMINER_FK FOREIGN KEY (EXAMINERID) REFERENCES EXAMINER,
CONSTRAINT STUDENT_FK FOREIGN KEY (STUDENTID) REFERENCES STUDENT,
CONSTRAINT ROUTE_FK FOREIGN KEY (ROUTEID) REFERENCES ROUTE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just first off I think you should look at the time functions of mysql. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime more specifically the addtime function.

I am not sure exactly what type is the column against which you are validating but the query does not seems to validate that column

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKINGS WHERE" + b1.getStartTime() + "<=" + b1.getStartTime() + "-" + maxTime + "AND" + b1.getStartTime() + ">=" + b1.getStartTime() + "+" + maxTime);
```

What are the bookings table columns for start time. Your query at run current will look like this:

```
select * from bookings where12<=12-5and12>=12+5
```

I would highly recommand you first use a string to assign your query string and use the console to output the statement so you can debug the statement easily without the rest of the application. I would also recommand you read about parameterized query because you are passing the user input right into the query and that is a big door open for SQL injection. See this link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

If you post you bookings table schema I am sure we can help you make up the right query based on your requirements.

**EDIT**

This might not be exactly the query you required but it will give you a good starting point. I highly suggest you debug the query first in sql plus of whatever tool you are using.

```
PreparedStatement prest;
Connection conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:");//set you jdbc url
String sql = "select * from bookings where bookingdate = ? and starttime between ? and ?";
prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
prest.setDate(1,b1.getBookingDate());
prest.setInt(2,b1.getStartTime()-5);
prest.setInt(3,b1.getStartTime()+5);
ResultSet rs1 = prest.executeQuery();
while(rs1.hasNexT())
    //extract data here
```

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to add in tables, i know the times are all over the place right now, but ill treat them as 4 digit numbers for now, untill i change it to time later on. Ill Update the question with the bookings table, thanks for being so helpful